# java data structure to hold many arrays of ints and their labels

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have input like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2,     A
0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2,     A
0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2,     B
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2,     A
```

With the letter being the label, and then numbers being the inputs.

I'd like to store this whole matrix in one data structure, such that the inputs that correspond to a particular label can be associated with it.

How to do this?

With a 2d array?

With an array list?

Hashmap?

Comment: Create a class with the following members: String label, int[] data

Comment: Do you need multiple rows of inputs per label? Here I see that there are 3 rows associated with A, do you need that?

Comment: yeah there are many rows associated with A, and many with B

Comment: Do you need to keep the same order of rows as well? or ordering is not of your concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your int array just replace the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Group {

   public String key;
   public String value;

   public String getKey() {
      return key;
   }

   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   Group(String v, String k) {
      this.key = k;
      this.value = v;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return this.key + " " + this.value;
   }
}

public class Datastructure {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(new Group("0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2", "A"));
      list.add(new Group("0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2", "A"));
      list.add(new Group("0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2", "B"));
      list.add(new Group("0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2", "A"));

      findKeyList(list, "A");
   }

   public static void findKeyList(ArrayList<Group> list, String search) {
      if (!list.isEmpty()) {
         for (Group element : list) {
            if (element.getKey().equals(search)) {
               System.out.println(element.toString());
            }
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `A, B,...` as keys, than you can use a HashMap with string as keys and arraylist as values

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Then you can iterate over your input and check if the map already contains the key.

```
for (...) {
    ...
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(value);
}
```

This is a generic example and you can do modifications based on your requirements.

Comment: when I tried to add the array it just output the location in memory, how can I be sure to add the array and all its elements?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English What do you mean that it was printing when you were adding? I didn't understand that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap :

```
Map<char, String[][]> matrix = new HashMap<char, String[]>();

matrix.put('A', new String[][]{{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2}, ...});
......
```

This way, many arrays could be associated with a single label (or character).

Comment: it's for a perceptron, so- as the labels will, many of them, be the same as others, I should make the key the array- is it?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. Just change the type from char to char[].

Comment: The hashmap should be keyed by the input? and the values should be the label?

Comment: The OP wants to maintain many rows associated with each key, a HashMap with a single value won't work here. You need a List of arrays

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is not a good solution for your case since there is no uniqueness in any of the attributes. Create a classwith 2 attributes:

```
Class Obj {
    char[] array;
    String label;
}
```

Then maintain a list of these objects as ArrayList

Comment: this sounds very reasonable but, can you please show me what they would look like in code? I've never done that before

Comment: I have shown the structure in my answer. When you receive input from user, you basically just construct objects of this type and add them to a list. What specific code are you looking for?

Comment: but then- don't i need some methods in there to populate it? getter and setter or w/e

Comment: Yes I assumed you would do that yourself